# CARDFILE.EXE stopped working on my Windows 10 pro. How can I access its .crd file?

Tags: windows, windows-10

error is: "This app can't run on you pc"

My cardfile.exe file is dated 1992.  This is the cardfile program that came with with all the old versions of Windows.

I've tried compatibility mode, but still get error.

I have a lot of contacts in the .crd file I'd like to access.

WHEN I DOUBLE-CLICK CARDFILE.EXE ON WIN10 (has been working on WIN10 64, but now gets this error as of Sept'2018
[image]

Comment: I half suspect its a 16 bit application - is your windows 10 64 bit?

Comment: Easiest seems to be to import with http://www.azzcardfile.com/cardfile/crd_file.html

Comment: If it is a 16-but application the only way would be to use a 32-bit VM.  16-bit applications cannot be ran on 64-bit installations of Windows.

Comment: Yes, my Win 10 is 64 bit, and cardfile.exe has been working on it for months.  But as of Sept2018 started failed.

Comment: LotPings: Azzcardfile.com does not open .CRD file from cardfile.exe

Answer (score -2):

Try this http://www.doeraene.be/programmes/eviedit.html
(It's in French but works very well !)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.